# How to create a table in PHP

Tags: php, html-table

I want to create a table in PHP with 33 staff numbers and 33 staff salaries. Each of the numbers are set my using `ran()` as shown in my code. When I run my code all the information comes up in 33 columns and two rows instead of two columns and 33 rows. How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
<? php

print "<table border ='2'><br /> ";
print "<tr>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 33; $i = $i + 1) {


  $staffnumber = rand(100000, 600000);
  print "<th>$staffnumber";

}
print "<tr>$i";

for ($j = 1; $j <= 33; $j = $j + 1) {
  $staffsalary = rand(14000, 40000);
  print "<th>$staffsalary";
}
print "<tr>$j";



print "</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: you are on the right track. 1. Learn about the composition of tables. 2. replace one of the `<th>` into `<tr><td>` inside the `for` loop

Comment: I don't see any closing `</th>` tags.

Comment: Sidenote: If `<? php` is part of your actual code, change it to `<?php` without the space.

Comment: Rather than using '$i = $i + 1' use '$I++ '

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print "<table border ='2'><br /> ";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 33; $i = $i + 1) {
  print "<tr>";

  $staffnumber = rand(100000, 600000);

  print "<td>$staffnumber</td>";
  $staffsalary = rand(14000, 40000);

  print "<td>$staffsalary</td>";

  print "</tr>";
}
print "</table>";

?>
```

You don't need 2 for cycles, because they have equal iterations

Answer (score 0):

First, determine your table structure. If you're unfamiliar with the markup, you should take a minute to review it (it's pretty simple): http://www.mountaindragon.com/html/tables2.htm

```
<table border="2">
    <thead>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         <!--- Iterate over this sequence -->
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>12345</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- End iteration -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then, find the part that repeats, and put it in a loop:

Notes:

- Used [heredoc](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3) for initial table code
- Used `$i++` syntax for `for` loop (instead of `$i = $i +`. It does the same thing, but most people use `$i++`.
- No need for second loop - do everything inside first loop
- Also, don't put things in the table outside of the `<td>` and `<tr>` tags.

..

```
echo <<<EOF
<table border="2">
    <thead>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
EOF;

for ($i=1; $i<=33;$i++) {
    $staffnumber = rand(100000, 600000);
    $staffsalary = rand(14000, 40000);
    echo "<tr><td>{$staffnumber}</td><td>{$staffsalary}</td></tr>";
}

echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = array();
for($i=0; $i<33; $i++) {
    $num = rand(1,10);
    $sal = rand(1,10);
    $data[] = array($num, $sal);
}
echo render_table($data);

function render_table(array $data) {
    $html = "<table>\n";
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $html .= "  <tr>\n";
        foreach ($row as $cell) {
            $html .= "    <td>$cell</td>\n";
        }
        $html .= "  </tr>\n";
    }
    $html .= "</table>\n";
    return $html;
}
```